# make XML schema extensible to newer versions

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, ambiguity, any

I have the following XML format that I want to make extensible. The root tag 'A' has several optional and mandatory fields (Ax) of different types (xs:string or self defined) that can occur in any order. The schema below works for me:

```
<xs:element name="A">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="A1" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="A2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <!-- AND MANY MORE -->
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Now I would like to make sure that a newer version of this XML still validates against a schema. With newer I mean: having more tags that are unknown to the XML schema. These new tags, just like the older ones, can occur in any order in the XML file. I tried adding

```
<xs:any />
```

in the schema at different places (at the bottom of the choice and sequence blocks), but I always get a schema invalid error. I understand how this causes my schema to be ambiguous, but I don't know how to solve my problem (maybe by having some extra restrictions like 'new tags can only be at the bottom' or something).